# Yeoman Angularjs How to Implement Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, directive

I'm trying to get my feet off the ground with Yeoman + Angular and going through the tutorials, I can't get even the most basic directives to fire, even when I try them exactly the same as in the tutorials.

Could someone please lend some insight as to what I'm missing, I've been struggling with this for the past 2 days

HTML template - ng-resize is the intended directive

```
<body ng-app="mvmdApp">
....
<div ng-mousemove="onMouse($event)" ng-resize="" class="youtube-cover ng-scope">
  <div class="youtube-unit"></div>
</div>
```

```
// controllers/youtube.js
'use strict';
angular.module('mvmdApp').controller('YoutubeCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('hi');// fires

  return $scope.onMouse = function(e) {}// fires
```

```
// directives/resize.js
'use strict';
angular.module('mvmdApp', []).directive('ngResize', function($window) {
  return function(scope) {
    return console.log('directive');// does not fire
  };
});
```

The strange thing is that whenever I even call `angular.module('mvmdApp', [])` like so from the directive script, it blocks the view from rendering.

edit: Also I noticed that when I load the directive before all the other scripts, it doesn't block the html from rendering, but it still doesn't trigger the directive. I don't know if/how the load order of angular scripts matters as I don't know where to find that.

Comment: Could you create a Plunker script with your code?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with plunkers angular library but here's basically it. I'm using coffeescript, stylus and jade, but here's the compiled code http://plnkr.co/edit/YHXOvbY33x2lcjotNxUX?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not solve your issue but one mistake i see is

`angular.module('mvmdApp', [])` been declared at multiple places, resize.js and app.js. This format declaration creates a new module everytime with this name.

This should be called once only from app.js. In resize.js it should be `angular.module('mvmdApp')`

Comment: Thanks, what threw me off was that the yeoman generator defined angular.module() twice, once in app.js and once in the controller main.js which made me believe it was a singleton pattern

Comment: can you update your question with this comment, this makes it easier for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the module multiple times.  You can simplify this by doing the following:

In app.js:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module("mvmdApp", []);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  ...
});
```

In youtube.js:

```
'use strict';
myApp.controller('YoutubeCtrl', function($scope) {
  ...
});
```

An in resize.js:

```
'use strict';

myApp.directive('resize', function($window) {
  ...
});
```

Updated plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/Im4SpcyH4cIem6TDWZaG?p=preview.  Also, I would refrain from calling the directive "ng-resize" as the ng prefix is usually used by the angular team.  In this case, the directive is simply "resize".

Comment: Thanks, in my case with coffee script which throws everything into it's own IIFE I had to define window.myApp = angular()... and redefine it in each script, but that seems to have fixed the issue, thanks